# Example on how to calculate a probability of a sequence of observations in HMM

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Given the following HMM model (from [Ankur Jain's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/~govind/CS661/Lec12.ppt&ei=P-7rUMCqMomP4gTN0oC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNF1BfpKrrg9smGc7SlRXEkVI0EJiA&sig2=QSgNY2dXgwEwF8VcPJcPKg&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.bGE) slides)

[image: an example of HMM]

A question with the answer is presented below:

[image]

We have the initial probabilities $P(\text{Low})=0.4$ and $P(\text{High})=0.6$.

However, I'm confused why in the solution we have an extra $0.4$. I guess it should be as follows

$$P(\text{Dry} \mid \text{Low}) P(\text{Rain} \mid \text{Low}) P(\text{Low})P(\text{Low}|\text{Low})
    = 0.4*0.6*0.4*0.3$$

Is the above correct?

Comment: It looks like your calculation is correct, unless I'm also missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. They have an extra $.4$.

Edit:

Let $Y_1,Y_2 \in \{\text{dry},\text{rain}\}$ be the two observations. Let $X_1, X_2 \in \{\text{low},\text{high}\}$ be the two unobserved state random variables.

\begin{align*}
P(y_1,y_2) &= \sum_{(x_1,x_2)}P(y_1,y_2 \mid x_1,x_2)p(x_1,x_2)\\
&= \sum_{(x_1,x_2)}P(y_1 \mid x_1)P(y_2 \mid x_2)p(x_1,x_2)\\
&= \sum_{(x_1,x_2)}P(y_1 \mid x_1)P(y_2 \mid x_2)p(x_2 \mid x_1)p(x_1).
\end{align*}
If we let $y_1,y_2 = (\text{dry},\text{rain})$ and we sum over the four possible pairs of the $x_i$s, then we get the probability of that particular sequence.

You were asking about one of those four particular summands, and to reiterate, yes, you are correct: 
$$
P(\text{Dry} \mid \text{Low}) P(\text{Rain} \mid \text{Low}) P(\text{Low})P(\text{Low}|\text{Low})
    = 0.4*0.6*0.4*0.3.
$$